# Correct Way to Fine-Tune/Train HuggingFace's Model from scratch (PyTorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

For example, I want to train a BERT model from scratch but using the existing configuration. Is the following code the correct way to do so?

```py
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
model.init_weights()
```

Because I think the `init_weights` method will re-initialize all the weights.

Second question, if I want to change a bit the configuration, such as the number of hidden layers.

```py
model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased', num_hidden_layers=10)
model.init_weights()
```

I wonder if the above is the correct way to do so. Because they don't appear to have an error when I run the above code.

Comment: For initializing the weights, the code seems fine.
To verify if the model has 10 layers, you can simply verify using `print(model)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this way, you would unnecessarily download and load the pre-trained model weights. You can avoid that by downloading the BERT config

```py
config = transformers.AutoConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
model = transformers.AutoModel.from_config(config)
```

Both yours and this solution assume you want to tokenize the input in the same as the original BERT and use the same vocabulary. If you want to use a different vocabulary, you can change in the config before instantiating the model:

```py
config.vocab_size = 123456
```

Similarly, you can change any hyperparameter that you want to have different from the original BERT.

Comment: This is pretty helpful. Thanks so much.

Comment: Just one comment. The code should be `AutoConfig.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")` right?